# Как организовать работу со списками(list)

Tags: c++, std-list

Дано последовательность с n элементов, нужно в начало поставить отрицательные числа а потом положительные, например есть последовательность {4, -3, 7, 1, -2, -45, 0, -2} программа должна вывести: -3 -2 -45 -2 4 7 1 0.

Нужно использовать библиотеку list.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef list<float> LISTINT;
LISTINT Min(LISTINT List, LISTINT Listv);
LISTINT Max(LISTINT List, LISTINT Listd);
LISTINT Firs(LISTINT Listv, LISTINT Listd);

void Out(LISTINT List);

void main() {

    LISTINT List;
    LISTINT Listd;
    LISTINT Listd_rew;
    LISTINT Listv;
    LISTINT ListVan;
    LISTINT::iterator i;

    int n;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        float k;
        cin >> k;
        List.insert(List.end(), k);
    }

    Out(List);
    Listv = Min(List, Listv);
    Listd = Max(List, Listd);
    ListVan = Firs(Listv, Listd);

    cout << endl;
    Out(ListVan);
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}

void Out(LISTINT List)
{   
    LISTINT::iterator i;
    for (i = List.begin(); i != List.end(); ++i)
        cout << *i << " ";
}

LISTINT Min(LISTINT List, LISTINT Listv)
{
    LISTINT::iterator i;
    for (i = List.begin(); i != List.end(); ++i) {
        if (0 > *i) {
            Listv.insert(Listv.end(), *i);
        }
    }
    return Listv;
}

LISTINT Max(LISTINT List, LISTINT Listd)
{
    LISTINT::iterator i;
    for (i = List.begin(); i != List.end(); ++i) {
        if (0 <= *i) {
            Listd.insert(Listd.end(), *i);
        }
    }
    return Listd;
}

LISTINT Firs(LISTINT Listv, LISTINT Listd)
{   
    LISTINT Listvan;
    Listvan.insert(Listvan.end(), Listv.begin(), Listv.end());
    Listvan.insert(Listvan.end(), Listd.begin(), Listd.end());  
    return Listvan;
}
```

Comment: Нужно - используйте. Но удовлетворите любопытство, что это за библиотека такая, `list`?

Comment: Интересно на вашем примере, какому всётаки закону подчиняется число -45, почему в  `-3 -2 -45 -2 4 7 1 0` оно между двойками?

Comment: все правильно - вначале выписываем все отрицательные, потом все положительные.

Comment: А вы просто отсортируйте - `list::sort()` разместит их именно так. Хотя это более сильное упорядочение, чем требуется...

Comment: потому что оно не сортирует, а просто по подряд записывает в начало, у меня уже код есть могу показать

Comment: что то вы слишком сложно делаете, ненужно никаких максимумов или минимумов искать (смотрите мой ответ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например можно так - берёте два итератора, один сначала идёт для положительных вставляя назад, другой с конца вставляя спереди отрицательные, всё очень просто

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::list<int> l = { 4, -3, 7, 1, -2, -45, 0, -2 };
    std::list<int> out;

    auto riter = l.rbegin();
    auto fiter = l.begin();

    while (riter != l.rend())
    {
        if (*riter < 0)
        {
            out.push_front(*riter);
        }

        if (*fiter >= 0)
        {
            out.push_back(*fiter);
        }

        riter++; fiter++;
    }

    for (auto iter = out.begin(); iter != out.end(); ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << *iter << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а как изменить порядок отрицательных чисел на обратный, а порядок неотрицательных сохраняется прежним, или наоборот

Comment: @user229552 ну, подумайте сами, я ведь не зря с конца иду для первого итератора ...

Comment: @user229552 если отрицательные хочется перевернуть, первый итератор тоже сначала должен идти

Comment: @user229552 аналогично (тоесть в обратном направлении) и для положительных

Comment: создам еще один список и потом лучше создать еще один цыкл, или в тех цыклах работать?

Comment: @user229552 в каких в тех цЫклах ? :D

Comment: ну не в ТЕХ, а в том

Comment: @user229552 я не понимаю о чём вы, ну, делайте так как требует ваша задача, алгоритм я написал

Comment: понял, спасибо за помощь :)

Answer (score 1):

Имеется стандартный алгоритм `std::stable_partition`, объявленный в заголовке `<algorithm>`,который разбивает множество элементов на две части согласно некоторому критерию и при этом сохраняет порядок следования элементов в последовательности.

Этот алгоритм возвращает итератор, который указывает на границу между двумя полученными подмножествами исходного множества.

Поэтому все, что вам требуется сделать, это просто вызвать этот алгоритм.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа вызова алгоритма.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::list<float> lst = { 4, -3, 7, 1, -2, -45, 0, -2 };

    for ( float x : lst ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto partition_point = std::stable_partition( lst.begin(), lst.end(), 
                                                  []( float x ) 
                                                  { 
                                                      return x < 0; 
                                                  } );

    for ( auto first = lst.begin(); first != partition_point; ++first )
    {
        std::cout << *first << ' ';
    }

    for ( auto first = partition_point; first != lst.end(); ++first )
    {
        std::cout << *first << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
4 -3 7 1 -2 -45 0 -2 
-3 -2 -45 -2 4 7 1 0
```

Не сложно также написать соответствующую программу для списка самостоятельно, на заводя при этом новый список. Аналогично стандартному алгоритму можно также получить итератор, который определяет границу между двумя полученными подмножествами исходного множества элементов.

Вот как это можно сделать.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() 
{
    std::list<float> lst = { 4, -3, 7, 1, -2, -45, 0, -2 };

    for ( float x : lst ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto partition_point = lst.begin();

    for ( auto current = lst.begin(); current != lst.end(); )
    {
        if ( *current < 0 )
        {
            if ( current != partition_point )
            {
                partition_point = lst.insert( partition_point, *current );
                current = lst.erase( current );
            }
            ++partition_point;
        }
        else
        {
            ++current;
        }
    }

    for ( auto first = lst.begin(); first != partition_point; ++first )
    {
        std::cout << *first << ' ';
    }

    for ( auto first = partition_point; first != lst.end(); ++first )
    {
        std::cout << *first << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
4 -3 7 1 -2 -45 0 -2 
-3 -2 -45 -2 4 7 1 0
```

Как видно из вывода на консоль обоих этих демонстрационных программ, порядок следования элементов после разбития исходного множества на подмножества сохраняется.